# Django 2.1: How to get a list of objects that in each object, contains the objects that have a foreign key pointing to them

Tags: python, django

I have these two classes:

```
Class A:
data

Class B:
a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

How can I get an array of `A` in which each `A` contains the `B`'s related to them?

I need it because I must return the two tables joined in a JSON.

Comment: With the above modeling, an `A` can have *zero*, *one*, or *more* `B`s related to `A`.

Comment: None of your classes is a Django model.

Comment: Because it's pseudocode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the back relation of `a` and then migrate the database:

```
Class A(models.Model):
    data

Class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='b_relations', null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now you can access the back relation. You need to call `.all()` on `b_relations` because it is lazy loaded.

```
A.objects.first().b_relations.all()
```

To get json data I suggest to use django rest framework's ModelSerializer:

```
class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = (
            'pk', # primary key
            'a',
        )
        depth = 0

class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    b_relations = BSerializer(many=True, read_only=True))

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = (
            'pk', # primary key
            'b_relations',
        )
        depth = 0
```

To get json data:

```
a_relations: QuerySet = A.objects.all()
serializer = ASerializer(a_relations, many=True)
json_data: Dict = serializer.data
```

In case you've never used Django Rest Framework: [Django Rest Framework - Getting Started](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation)

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much, it's been very helpful and now it works!